# Motion of a projectile

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

We all are aware how we can use the forces and vectors to describe a classical projectile motion (No drag forces).
Major things we already know include:

1. Position-time dependence of projectiles
2. Range of projectile
3. Distance traversed by projectile
4. Curvature at any point

My question relates to a 3D-Geometrical interpretation of the motion.

Consider a cubical environment with appropriate dimensions and align the x,y,z axes with the cube.
We start a projectile at one of the bottom corner and throw it such that it reaches the diagonally opposite corner. Take the angle of launch to be $\theta$ and the initial velocity as $u$.

**My interests and questions:**

1. I want to find the system of equations of planes which will intersect at a point and give me the coordinates.
2. How many varieties of such planes are possible?

Comment: I have some difficulty understanding your questions.First of all, how is the angle of launch measured? that is, which respect to which axis or other vector? And the coordinates of what, in your first question?

Comment: @pglpm ...There are certainly many loop holes, i think I'll delete it, it doesn't look good. It was just a thought experiment to trace the trajectory of a projectile using an intersection of 3 planes

Comment: Maybe it just needs some rephrasing rather than deletion. But consider that the very notion of *coordinate* is defined (in $\mathbf{R}^3$) in terms of intersection of planes.

If you ask how many triples of non-coincident planes pass through a given point, the answer is "$\infty^{9}$" if I'm not mistaken; that is, they form a space with 9 dimensions. If you want them orthogonal then it's 4 dimensions. Check [Grassmannians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian). So for each point of the trajectory there's a 9-dimensional space of plane triples passing through it.

Comment: @pglpm this is informative, thanks, I'll check it out, I think I presented the easiest to find planes in my answer?

Comment: You're welcome. Mmm... sorry I don't understand what you mean. What's easiest? I still don't quite understand which planes you have in mind...

Comment: @pglpm First plane: Plane of projectile, second plane: plane tangent to the $r$ vector, third plane:Plane along radius of curvature

Comment: It looks like you essentially want to use a different coordinate system. The plane that contains the trajectory is unique. But you have infinite different planes tangent to the $r$ vector (the plane of the trajectory is one, for example). And the planes containing the circles of curvature are all the same as the trajectory plane. So this kind of choice is ill-posed for two different reasons.

Comment: @pglpm got it, I was wondering the same. So, how would you describe unique planes given this question?

Comment: That's what I don't understand. When you have the Cartesian $x,y,z$ coordinates of the projectile as functions of time, they already describe at each time three planes that intersect at that point. If you use, say, polar coordinates $r,\theta,\phi$, they also describe three (tangent) planes that intersect at that point. So I don't know what other kinds of planes you have in mind and why.

Comment: @pglpm you're right....what did i do... :/ I have been forcibly making my coordinate systems

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi, I suspect that your problem is under-specified.  For a 3D projectile motion problem, you probably need to specify two angles and a starting velocity.

Comment: @DavidWhite I mentioned that it's launched diagonally, just that the angle is from the ground would be enough

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi, the general specification would require you to state an angle with respect to the x-axis, an angle with respect to elevation, and a velocity.  If you fix the angle with respect to the x-axis, you could just as easily rotate the axes and turn this into a 2D problem.  So, my question is: are you actually looking for a 3D solution?

Comment: @DavidWhite yes, it would require 2 angle, I am looking for the equation of planes which upon intersection yields the position, but i now see it's not that good to follow this, it just has no value in it self

Answer (score 2):

That movement is ruled by an acceleration, which is the second derivative of position.

That means that you only need to specify two things: initial position, and initial velocity, (That includes magnitude and direction).

Given the initial position and the velocity, the plane in which the movement occurs is perfectly determined. So you would just choose that plane and work in two dimensions. It is not necessary to complicate it.

However, if you want to work in 3D, you can also do it. Just split your initial position and your initial velocity into its three components and you've got it:

$$ \begin{cases} \displaystyle x=x_0+v_{ox}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_x t^2 \\
y=y_0+v_{oy}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_y t^2 \\
 z=z_0+v_{oz}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_z t^2
\end{cases} $$

---

Edit:

Now that I see your comment, I understand what you mean.

Of course there are infinite possible moving planes whose intersection is one moving point.

The easiest solution is the one I said, just set:

$$ \begin{cases} \displaystyle x=x_0+v_{ox}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_x t^2 \\
y=y_0+v_{oy}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_y t^2 \\
 z=z_0+v_{oz}t+ \frac{1}{2} a_z t^2
\end{cases} $$

and those are actually three planes. The first one is $x=x_{particle}$, and so on.

Then, since they are planes

**Any linear combination of those planes gives you another plane with the same solution**.

That's the key of linear equations.

Check that all those planes depend on a parameter: $t$, which coincides with the time, but it is a free parameter after all.

One last thing, check that this question should belong to Mathematics SE

Comment: I think the question asked to find equation of planes , you've described $r$ as a position of time

Comment: You can use this as an addition to the community wiki i made

Comment: You can always find the equation of a plane given two points and a vector...

Comment: I think the question is very unclear, i should delete it... it's actually a thought experiment to trace the coordinates of a projectile using the intersection of 3 planes

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi you don't have to delete it, just edit it to make it clear. I don't understand what you mean with "coordiantes using intersection of 3 planes". Are you asking for the position of the projectile $\vec{r}(t)$ as intersection of 3 planes? Then choose the coordinates themselves:  $x=x_p; y=y_p; z=z_p$

Comment: yes right...till now i had something else in mind which was way more complex. Please edit something in your answer i want to upvote

Comment: So you are asking how to find 3 planes which intersect in the points (x,y,z) of the projectile. Since the projectile moves, the planes must be moving, and you want to find the equations of those planes. Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly , I tried doing so by the method i indicated but it seems there are infinitely many such planes possible.

Comment: Okay then, now it's lcear. You can see the edit, but you should also edit your question to clarify that. Also, it would be interesting to know why you're looking for this

Comment: And yes I will update my question, I was mainly concerned about it because as i was studying the lagrangian/hamiltonian method I came across the jacobian determinant